Does this finitely-generated algebra have a name?
I've been led to consider certain finitely-generated algebras that arise from some Coxeter groups (finite and affine Weyl groups at least).  As a very concrete example, consider the infinite dihedral group $G = \langle s,t : s^2 = t^2 = 1 \rangle$.  In this case, I am led to consider the associative unital algebra (over whatever base field $k$):
$$A = k \langle u,v : u^3 = u, \  v^3 = v, \  u^2 v^2 = v^2 u^2 \rangle.$$
Has anyone seen or studied such algebras before?  I'm interested in its finite-dimensional modules.  I can keep chugging... but maybe it has a name?
